# AmCharts adding dataset with only events

Tags: amcharts

One of our series has no data points but only events. Playing with your example here http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/9589aaoh/light/, I had commented out the dataprovider (set it to empty array):

```
dataProvider: [],
categoryField: "date",
compared: true,
stockEvents: stockEvents
```

Looking at the result, it seems that amCharts doesn't support events without datapoints. Can someone confirm?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to confirm that it is indeed the case. Events without corresponding datapoints will not be rendered.